# Using substring of one column to populate blanks in a second column BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a list of suppliers and a list of their orders where some of the suppliers are `null` but they're identifiable by the first 3 characters of the order number, i.e a `TS1` will always be `Tesco` and an `AS2` will always be `Asda`.

| Supplier | Order |
| --- | --- |
| Tesco | TS1123 |
| Asda | AS2123 |
| Sainsb | SB1123 |
| TescoM | TSM1123 |
| null | TS1124 |

I've tried to create a join where only supplier is filled in using a `WHERE NOT NULL` clause but it's created a massive table with tons of duplicates

```
WITH 
Supplier_fixed AS 
(Select 
Adb.supplier_name AS supplier_a,
Adb.order AS order_a,
Bdb.supplier AS supplier_b,
Bdb.order AS order_b
FROM `Database' AS Adb
LEFT JOIN `Database' AS Bdb
ON Substr(adb.order, 1,3) = Substr(bdb.order, 1,3)
WHERE Bdb.supplier_name IS NOT NULL)

Select DISTINCT order_a, supplier_b
FROM supplier_fixed
Order BY supplier_b
```

All I really want is a table that looks like this

| Supplier | Order | Sup_fixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tesco | TS1123 | Tesco |
| Asda | AS2123 | Asda |
| Sainsb | SB1123 | Sainsb |
| TescoM | TSM1123 | TescoM |
| NULL | TS1124 | Tesco |

There has to be a more efficient way of doing the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MAX** analytic function.

```sql
SELECT *, MAX(Supplier) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(`Order`, 3)) Sup_fixed
  FROM `Database`;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- [MAX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#max) returns the maximum non-*NULL* value in an aggregated group.